# Colorbox Iframe name keeps changing so I cannot selectFrame with Selenium

Tags: selenium, colorbox

I'm trying to automate a simple page that has a colorbox that loads an iFrame inside.  Whenever I record a test in Selenium it captures the iframe just fine.  But then when I re-run the test it cannot grab the iframe inside.  I looked into it and you'll see this code:

Command: selectFrame
Target: iframe_1313186641607
Value: (blank)

I go to Firefox and inspect element and I see:

```
<div>
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 558px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 698px; height: 558px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 698px; overflow: auto; height: 530px;">
<iframe id="cboxIframe" frameborder="0" src="SelectCourseOptions.aspx?courseno=111&subject=ACC&term=Fall 2010" name="iframe_1313186641607">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body style="background-color: White">
<form id="form1" action="SelectCourseOptions.aspx?courseno=111&subject=ACC&term=Fall+2010" method="post" name="form1">
<div>
```

So you can see it's matching on the "name" of the iframe.  Then, I'll go re-run the test and it can't select the iframe, I'll inspect element again and see this:

```
<div>
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 558px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 698px; height: 558px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 698px; overflow: auto; height: 530px;">
<iframe id="cboxIframe" frameborder="0" src="SelectCourseOptions.aspx?courseno=111&subject=ACC&term=Fall 2010" name="iframe_1313186725931">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body style="background-color: White">
<form id="form1" action="SelectCourseOptions.aspx?courseno=111&subject=ACC&term=Fall+2010" method="post" name="form1">
<div>
```

Now you can see that the iframe name:

name="iframe_1313186725931"

That is different from the first time when I recorded the test:

name="iframe_1313186641607"

Just for fun I closed the colorbox and re-opened and the name changed again.  How can I work around this?  It seems colorbox just generates a dynamic name every time so I can't select it in Selenium?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, I was just being a Selenium n00b.  I needed to select the colorbox by id instead of by the name tag.  Like this:

Command: selectFrame Target: id=cboxIframe Value: (blank)

That works!

Answer (score 0):

In case others are having a similar issue with dynamic iframes, note i've used php selenium webdriver "facebook":

```
$iFrame = $webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//iframe[@id="cboxIframe"]'));
```

or

```
$iFrame = $webDriver>findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//iframe[@class="cboxIframe"]'));
```

or

```
$iFrame = $webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//iframe[@name="cboxIframe"]'));
```

And finally switch focus to iFrame

```
$webDriver->switchTo()->frame($iFrame);
```